# How do I calculate averages of dates formatted as VARCHAR from multiple rows?

Tags: sql, datetime, varchar, datediff

I'm  having an issue where I am running a script against a database to get the average difference between multiple VARCHARs that need to be converted to DateTimes, and then take the average between all the results.

My code is:

```
SELECT YEAR(b.DateAcknow),AVG(datediff(dd,convert(datetime,b.DateAssign),
convert(datetime,b.DateResolv))) as DayAverage, 
AVG(datediff(hh,convert(datetime,b.TimeAcknow),  
convert(datetime,b.TimeResolv))) as HourAverage

FROM      table AS b              
WHERE     (x = y) 
AND YEAR(DateResolv) >= 2006
AND YEAR(DateResolv) < 2016
AND  b.resolution <>''

GROUP BY YEAR(b.DateAcknow)
ORDER BY YEAR(b.DateAcknow)`
```

The result I'm getting does not seem to make sense, much less it includes 1900 which falls outside of my parameters of the where clause

Here it is:

```
NULL        42          NULL
1900        0           12
2006        7           -5
2007        6           1
2008        7           1
2009        4           1
2010        2           0
2011        2           0
2012        2           0
2013        2           0
2014        2           0
2015        2           0
```

Am I converting the `VARCHAR`s wrong?

I doubt that the average for thousands of entries from 2010-2015 are all the same 2 days and 0 hours too, so either I'm doing something wrong or the data is bad.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  My intention is to display for each year what the average response time is in Days and Hours.

Comment: Without example data it's difficult to see what's happening... could it be that since 2010 all dates are stored with an empty timestamp? That would explain the 0 hours differences. As for the days, if management wants calls to be closed after 2 days, it is well possible that most of them are, leading to an average of 2 days (I don't know if AVG returns anything but int if you average integers?)

Comment: Also, your days and hours are not part of the same timespan, although your phrasing seems to imply that.

Comment: @oerkelens Although they are two separate fields they are the same timespan.  One just is a date(DateAssign-DateResolv) and the other is just a 24 hour clock time(TimeAcknow-TimeResolv).

Comment: So DateAssign is the same as DateAcknow? Otherwise they are two different timespans, one expressed in days, the other in hours. Note that the one in hours supposedly returns the total amount of hours, _not_ the "hours" part of the timespan (so that would be 48 hours for two days).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filtering by DateResolv and group by DateAcknow.

Filter and group by the same Field and NULL and values outside of the Range should disappear.

Comment: So I made the proper changes to get rid of the NULL values- bu tI still have the 2 day average and 0 hour average for each entry.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to take away the aggregate part and just run:

```
SELECT YEAR(b.DateAcknow)
, convert(datetime,b.DateAssign) AS DateAssignDateTime
, convert(datetime,b.DateResolv) AS DateResolveDateTime
, datediff(dd,convert(datetime,b.DateAssign), convert(datetime,b.DateResolv)) AS AssignResolveDayDiff
, convert(datetime,b.TimeAcknow) AS TimeAcknowDateTime
, convert(datetime,b.TimeResolv) AS TimeResolveDateTime
, datediff(hh,convert(datetime,b.TimeAcknow), convert(datetime,b.TimeResolv)) AS AcknowResolveHourDiff
FROM      table AS b              
WHERE     (x = y) 
AND YEAR(DateAcknow) >= 2006
AND YEAR(DateAcknow) < 2016
AND  b.resolution <>''
ORDER BY YEAR(b.DateAcknow)
```

To ensure that all of your conversions are making sense first.  Then you will have a better understanding of what it is you're actually averaging.

Afterwards, if it all checks out, then your query should work fine (though, do check that mxix' change from

```
...
AND YEAR(DateResolv) >= 2006
AND YEAR(DateResolv) < 2016
...
```

to

```
...
AND YEAR(b.DateAcknow) >= 2006
AND YEAR(b.DateAcknow) < 2016
...
```

makes sense for you.

If you're looking to increase the precision of the output, then try converting your datediffs like so:
Old: `AVG(datediff(dd,convert(datetime,b.DateAssign), convert(datetime,b.DateResolv)))`

New: `AVG(Convert(Decimal(10, 5), datediff(dd,convert(datetime,b.DateAssign), convert(datetime,b.DateResolv))))`

Your old query is averaging days, rounded to the nearest integer value, giving you values like '2'.  This new adjustment will give you answers like "1.51235" days instead.

Since there's 100k records of differences (both plus and minus), there's a good chance the averages will be close to zero if they follow a normal or uniform distribution.  Also try:
`AVG(Convert(Decimal(10, 5), ABS(datediff(dd,convert(datetime,b.DateAssign), convert(datetime,b.DateResolv)))))`

if you want absolute difference instead.  If your old data had values "5, -3, 4, -1, 3", then the old method would produce the average of 2, but if you had the "ABS" function working on them, it would change the values to "5, 3, 4, 1, 3" and will move your resulting average in the ++ direction (here, it changes to "3", or "3.2", if you did your decimal conversion too).

Comment: Running what you suggested does return the correct data.

Comment: So can you spot the problem?  Maybe if you were to post the results of this query, and the desired outcome of the aggregate, I could spot the logical error.  You may need to use an ABS function on your differences, and/or convert them to decimal types before averaging to get 'appropriate' results.

Comment: It contains sensitive data results so sadly I cannot do that.  It is returning about 100,000 records as well.  The odds that they are all average 2 days and 0 hours even with rounding not being in the decimals is honestly PowerBall odds.

Comment: You may want to output the values for the year with the smallest number of records and do the math manually in a spreadsheet to check it.  (Also, see the edits to my answer above)

Answer (score 0):

> My intention is to display for each year what the average response
>   time is in Days and Hours. – obizues

Assuming:

1. DateAcknow is a varchar date with an empty timestamp (e.g., "2011/01/15")
2. TimeAcknow is DateAcknow's corresponding varchar time (e.g., "15:35")
3. DateResolve is a varchar date with an empty timestamp (e.g., "2011/01/16") which is always greater than or equal to DateAcknow
4. TimeResolve is DateResolve's corresponding varchar time (e.g., "13:47")
5. You want to average total hours difference (using the above example, this record's hours difference is 22)

If you need help with your varchar date's format and the convert function, see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

The following approach should work to achieve your intention:

```
SELECT YEAR(b.DateAcknow)
, AVG(DateDiff(Day, Convert(datetime, b.DateAcknow) + convert(datetime, b.TimeAcknow), Convert(datetime, b.DateResolv) + Convert(datetime, b.TimeResolve)))  AS AvgDaysDifference
, AVG(DateDiff(Hour, Convert(datetime, b.DateAcknow) + convert(datetime, b.TimeAcknow), Convert(datetime, b.DateResolv) + Convert(datetime, b.TimeResolve)))  AS AvgHoursDifference
FROM      table AS b              
WHERE (x = y) AND YEAR(DateAcknow) >= 2006 AND YEAR(DateAcknow) < 2016
   AND  b.resolution <>''
GROUP BY YEAR(b.DateAcknow)
```

This should do it if the assumptions about your data and your intention are correct.  It is difficult to help when it's not clear.